# nvd3.js : no mouseover datapoint effects in a line chart on updating the chart

Tags: d3.js, linechart, nvd3.js

I'm trying to draw a simple line chart using nvd3/d3. Things are fine when the graph loads for the first time. But whenever I load new data and update the graph, the transition that occurs on the datapoints during 'mouseover' is lost. The tooltip is shown though. How to fix this?.

have a look at this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lkshminarayanan/af4nK/1/).

adding the code :

```
//js :

    var n = 0;

var data = function (start) {
    var line1 = [],
        line2 = [];

    for (var i = start; i < start + 50; i++) {
        line1.push({
            x: i,
            y: 2 * i
        });
        line2.push({
            x: i,
            y: 3 * i
        });
    }

    return [{
        values: line1,
        key: 'y = 2 * x',
        color: '#ff7f0e'
    }, {
        values: line2,
        key: 'y = 3 * x',
        color: '#2ca02c'
    }];
}

var drawGraph = function (start) {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart();

    chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Time (ms)')
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

    chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
        .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(data(start))
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
}

nv.addGraph(drawGraph(n));

$("button").click(function () {
    n += 50;
    nv.addGraph(drawGraph(n));
});
```

the html page :

```
<div id="chart">
<svg></svg>
</div>
<button>Change Graph</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need is actually much simpler than what you have. You only need to create the chart object once and don't need to call `nv.addGraph()` either. I've updated the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/af4nK/2/); the relevant code is also below.

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart();

chart.xAxis
  .axisLabel('Time (ms)')
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

chart.yAxis
  .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
  .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

var drawGraph=function(start) {
  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data(start))
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
}

drawGraph(n);

$("button").click(function(){
  n += 50;
  drawGraph(n);
});
```

All the actual drawing work is done in the line `.call(chart)`.